# Matrix annotation in raw Markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to create a matrix with annotation, similar to what 3Blue1Brown does [here](https://youtu.be/XkY2DOUCWMU?t=202):

[image: Underbracket]

(I don't need to be so fancy with the curly bracket, I just want the caption.) I saw [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462617/168037) relating to LaTeX packages, but I'm writing this in a Jupyter notebook that will end up on GitHub, which uses pretty raw Markdown functionality.

Is there a way to do this using raw Markdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) in a code block to achieve this:

```
┏       ┓
┃ 1   1 ┃
┃       ┃
┃ 0   1 ┃
┗       ┛
  Shear
```